# UISearchBar animation issue using UISearchDisplayController

Tags: objective-c, ios7, ios8, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UITableViewController` whose table view is displaying a list of calendar entries.
The controller is created programatically and is embedded in a `UINavigationController`.

In the view controller's viewDidLoad method I'm calling another method to instantiate a `UISearchBar` and a `UISearchDisplayController`.

Here's the code that does that:

```
- (void)configureSearch {
UISearchBar *searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
self.sdc = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar
                                             contentsController:self];

self.sdc.delegate = self;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
}
```

Doing so, I'm seeing a strange animation issue where the search bar "snaps" into place when it becomes and resigns first responder status.

Attached video shows this behaviour and normals speed and with slow animations enabled.

Link to the screen recording is [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpunwm7kwkariyp/Search%20bar%20animation%20issue.mov?dl=0)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `-[UISearchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:NO]` from within a `UIView` animation block has solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `translucent = YES` on your `UINavigationBar`. I had the exact same problem and for some reason that fixed it.

Comment: Your suggestion solved the animation issue, but it leaves me with a translucent navigation bar, which is something I don't want in.